# how to list all function of man page 9

Tags: linux, man

I did "man copy_to_user" - It shows some kernel help text. It belongs to section 9. Now I would like to know ,whether is there way to display all function belongs to this section 9.

Comment: All functions that belongs to all software on section 9?..

Comment: Yes,list all functions that belongs to section 9. I'm interested in functions.I can see them under /usr/share/man/man9 . But would like to know anyother better way to list them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whatis -s 9 -w "*"` will list the name and descriptions of all the manpages it knows about (uses the `mandb` database) in section 9.  Be sure to quote the `*` character.

Comment: It says unknown option. `[laks@space ~]$ whatis --version
whatis from man-1.6f 
[laks@space ~]$ whatis -s  9 -w "*"
whatis: -s: unknown option`

Comment: I've got `whatis 2.5.7` which is in debian stable's man-db 2.5.7-8 package.  Even oldstable has 2.5.2.  Check `man whatis` and see if your version has some other way of specifying section and wildcard matches.